# Rails Mailer quoted-printable replace = by =3D

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encoding, actionmailer, quoted-printable

I've been facing this bug for a long time now, read a lot of "solution" but none works for me.

When I send an email with Rails, I received it but all my image on it are not working because of this quoted-printable issue.

For example I have this code in my views/user_mailer/confirmation.html.erb

```
<img src="mydomain.com/logo.gif"/>
```

When I received it, in the source code I can see (and it's not working) :

```
<img alt=3D"mydomain.com/logo.gif" />
```

All other `=` are transformed into `=3D`.

The mail is :

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
```

What could be the solution, I already tried plenty of them without success...

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could be wrong, but I don't think you can have just `example.com/logo.gif` for an image src in html emails.  You need to specify the protocol -- `http://example.com/logo.gif`.  At least Apple Mail is this way.